# Why are unauthenticated requests allowed in custom policies?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using cookie auth with the following settings:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = false,
            ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0)
        });
```

I've assumed that using the `[Authorize]` attribute with a policy declared requires a user to be authenticated before evaluating custom requirements, however, it's not the case.

This has also been attempted (note the call to `RequireAuthenticatedUser()`):

```
options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy",
                policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.Requirements.Add(
                        new SomeRequirement(serviceProvider.GetService<IMyService>()));
                });
```

However, even then, in my `AuthorizationHandler` for `SomeRequirement`, `HandleRequirementAsync()` still gets executed. Why?

I really, really, really don't want to check if user is authenticated in every `AuthenticationHandler` like this:

```
if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    context.Fail();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't want to deal with unauthenticated requests in your custom policies? Do what's listed in [blowdart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2525/blowdart)'s ASP.NET Authorization Workshop on GitHub: [authorize all endpoints with a default policy](https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetAuthorizationWorkshop#step-2-authorize-all-the-things).

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                 .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                 .Build();
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

Then use `[AllowAnonymous]` where needed.

Answer (score 4):

That's by design. When you specify a custom authorization policy, you **replace** the default one. The workaround is simple:

```
[Authorize(Policy="foo")]
[Authorize]
```

This combines your policy AND default policy.

Explanation: this is how policies are combined: [AuthorizationPolicy](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/AuthorizationPolicy.cs#L159). You could see `policyProvider.GetDefaultPolicyAsync()` is called only if `authorizeDatum.Policy` is empty (i.e. if custom policy is not specified).

FYI: default policy has only one requirement: [DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/22d2fe99c6fd9806b36025399a217a3a8b4e50f4/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/Infrastructure/DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement.cs).
Its essential part is:

```
if (!userIsAnonymous)
{
    context.Succeed(requirement);
}
return TaskCache.CompletedTask;
```

So it doesn't fail on an anonymous user, it passes control-flow to the next requirement. Chain of requirements will continue until explicit `context.Fail()` call or chain's end. To fail-fast on an anonymous user, write the custom requirement:

```
if (userIsAnonymous) context.Fail()
```

And place it first in the list (order of handlers here determines their execution order in request pipeline):

```
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, CustomFailAuthorizationRequirementHandler>();
//Register other authorization handlers
```

Default `DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement` can be overriden with this custom requirement (requirement handler will be called on every authorization (custom or default)):

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .AddRequirements(new CustomFailAuthorizationRequirement)
        .Build();
            
        //Add other policies

});
```

Comment: Adding the default `[Authorize]` on a controller also decorated with `[Authorize(Policy="SomePolicy")]` still results in that policy's auth handler getting executed - what I don't want.  Also, wouldn't this line `policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();` above in `AddPolicy()` be doing the same thing?

Comment: @steamrolla then you could write custom requirement with explicit `context.Fail()` call instead of usage default one. I added some details to the answer. And you're right, `RequireAuthenticatedUser()` adds the ` DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement`  to requirements list.