# IdentityServer: Multiple Clients with different grant types, policies not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, identityserver4, policies

I've got an identity server setup with the following 'look a like' configuration:

```
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                [...]
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                [....]
            },
            new Client
            {
                [...]
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                [....]
            }
        };
```

and controlles annotated like this:

```
    [Route("api/forms")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(Policy = "user.api.portfolio.manager")]
    [Authorize(Policy = "application.api.portfolio.manager")]
   public class FormsController : ControllerBase
   {
      [...]
   }
```

and a policy

```
        private System.Action<AuthorizationOptions> AddJwtAuthorizationPolicyForRole()
        {
            return options => { options.AddPolicy("**POLICY_FOR_GRANT_IMPLICIT**", policy => { 
                policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); 
                policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "USER_ACCESSIBLE");
            }); 
            };
        }

        private System.Action<AuthorizationOptions> AddJwtAuthorizationPolicyForRole()
        {
            return options => { options.AddPolicy("**POLICY_FOR_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS**", policy => { 
                policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); 
                policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
            }); 
            };
        }
```

so I want to achieve:

Clients using the GrantType.ClientCredentials can access the controller without any further needs.
Clients using the Implicit Schema must have role USER_ACCESSIBLE

If it's configured like shown above, both policies must apply -> Both grant types are failing.

How can I achieve the described behavior using IdentityServer, that each grant-types may have an independent policy so be applied?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The most simplest solution is adding another single policy for Implicit + ClientCredential to implement logics for OR conditions .

Or you can create a custom attribute like :

- `MultiplePolicysAuthorizeAttribute`

  ```
  public class MultiplePolicysAuthorizeAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
  {
       public MultiplePolicysAuthorizeAttribute(string policys, bool isAnd = false) : base(typeof(MultiplePolicysAuthorizeFilter))
       {
           Arguments = new object[] { policys, isAnd };
       }
  }
  ```
- MultiplePolicysAuthorizeFilter

  ```
  public class MultiplePolicysAuthorizeFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
  {
      private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorization;
      public string Policys { get; private set; }
      public bool IsAnd { get; private set; }

      public MultiplePolicysAuthorizeFilter(string policys, bool isAnd, IAuthorizationService authorization)
      {
         Policys = policys;
         IsAnd = isAnd;
         _authorization = authorization;
      }

      public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
      {
          var policys = Policys.Split(";").ToList();
          if (IsAnd)
          {
              foreach (var policy in policys)
              {
                  var authorized = await _authorization.AuthorizeAsync(context.HttpContext.User, policy);
                  if (!authorized.Succeeded)
                  {
                      context.Result = new ForbidResult();
                      return;
                  }

              }
           }
           else
           {
              foreach (var policy in policys)
              {
                   var authorized = await _authorization.AuthorizeAsync(context.HttpContext.User, policy);
                   if (authorized.Succeeded)
                   {
                       return;
                   }

              }
              context.Result = new ForbidResult();
              return;
          }
       }
  }
  ```

If actions require matching one of the policies(OR):

```
[MultiplePolicysAuthorize("POLICY_FOR_GRANT_IMPLICIT;POLICY_FOR_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS")]
```

If actions require matching all the policies(And) :

```
[MultiplePolicysAuthorize("POLICY_FOR_GRANT_IMPLICIT;POLICY_FOR_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS",true)]
```

Code sample reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52639938/5751404

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It seems to be working. But isn't there any built-in way to achieve this behavior - as my problem seems like a quite common one.

Comment: No , there is no built-in options to do that , or you can use multi handler in one requirement : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1#why-would-i-want-multiple-handlers-for-a-requirement

Comment: hmm, cannot get the MultiplePolicyAuthorize implementation to work, my user object is not (yet?) set during the call - is there any other step to take?

Comment: No other steps and confirm 1. you correctly set the polices  2. correctly use AddJwtBearer extension to validate token and create user princple 3. set    app.UseAuthentication(); app.UseAuthorization(); in Configure method