# Can Blazor Use Custom IAuthorizationFilter

Tags: authorization, blazor

Hi I was trying to use TypeFilter and IAuthorizationFilter like discussed in these post:

[How do you create a custom AuthorizeAttribute in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464359/how-do-you-create-a-custom-authorizeattribute-in-asp-net-core) and [How to include multiple policies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69321153/423356)
for blazor (server side, not blazor wasm, not asp.net core), but the IAuthorizationFilter is never executed.

I want to use IAuthorizationFilter, because using custom policy requirement and IAuthorizationHandler is so not flexible.

I cannot find explicitly that IAuthorizationFilter and Blazor don't work together, every keyword using blazor and custom filter only point to using that policy requirement IAuthorizationRequirement.

So anybody has their blazor server side application works with IAuthorizationFilter? would you mind sharing your resources.

Thank you.

updated:

This is the codes I used from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43788693/423356

```
public enum PermissionItem
{
    User,
    Product,
    Contact,
    Review,
    Client
}

public enum PermissionAction
{
    Read,
    Create,
}


public class AuthorizeAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public AuthorizeAttribute(PermissionItem item, PermissionAction action)
    : base(typeof(AuthorizeActionFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { item, action };
    }
}

public class AuthorizeActionFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly PermissionItem _item;
    private readonly PermissionAction _action;
    public AuthorizeActionFilter(PermissionItem item, PermissionAction action)
    {
        _item = item;
        _action = action;
    }
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        bool isAuthorized = MumboJumboFunction(context.HttpContext.User, _item, _action); // :)

        if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I declare in my blazor server side .NET 5.0 page:

```
@attribute [Authorize]
@attribute [Authorize(PermissionItem.User, PermissionAction.Read)]
```

Using Custom policy requirement works but not flexible, as explained better in my 2 sources above.

Comment: Which Blazor ? __

Comment: So show us some code - "but the IAuthorizationFilter is never executed".  There are 15 answers to your first quoted reference.  Which one are you trying to use?

Comment: for Blazor .NET 5.0 the sample codes I used are from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43788693/423356 derived from https://stackoverflow.com/a/41348219/423356 also explained here https://blog.iamdavidfrancis.com/posts/aspnet-filter-dependency-injection/ I use it in my Blazor page using @attribute [Authorize(PermissionItem.User, PermissionAction.Read)]

Comment: already updated my post: Blazor Server + code

Comment: I'm pretty sure `IAuthorizationFilter` isn't part of Blazor Authorizarion - I had a quick look through the codebase.  You say "IAuthorizationHandler" isn't flexible enough.  I think your wrong.  Here's a GitHub Repo of mine that shows how to implement policy based authorization based on record information.  You can pass your attribute data into the AuthorizationHander.  I'll post an answer based on the Repo if you want. https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.Authorization