# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Custom RoleProvider with Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, roles

I am migrating applications away from the ASP.Net MVC 5 framework to the new .Net Core 2.1.

I used Windows Authentication with a Custom RoleProvider in the MVC 5 Projects as shown in the link below.

[ASP.NET MVC How to create a custom role provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940905/asp-net-mvc-how-to-create-a-custom-role-provider)

How do I accomplish the same in Core 2.1 as it does not seem to contain RoleProvider capability?

Every example I come across uses Individual Accounts with IdentityUser and IdentityRole.

My custom tables for User and Roles :

```
public class User
{
    public User() { UserRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>(); }

    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string Logon { get; set; } //The users Active Directory Username

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

}


public class Role
{
    public Role() { UserRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>(); }

    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Edit:

I've added a CustomClaimsPrincipal which goes like:

```
public class CustomClaimsPrincipal : ClaimsPrincipal
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public CustomClaimsPrincipal(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public override bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        var currentUser = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name;

        IdentityUser user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(currentUser, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
            //(ApplicationUser)_context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(currentUser, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

        var roles = from ur in _context.UserRoles.Where(p => p.UserId == user.Id)
                    from r in _context.Roles
                    where ur.RoleId == r.Id
                    select r.Name;
        if (user != null)
            return roles.Any(r => r.Equals(role, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

and added to Startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddScoped<ClaimsPrincipal, CustomClaimsPrincipal>();
```

But it still seems to be taking the original ClaimsPrincipal IsInRole function instead of the override which I believe is why I'm getting the error message "The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed."

Comment: The duplicate you mention is for Individual Accounts which uses IdentityUser which is not used in Windows Authentication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managing custom permissions in net core is usually done via claims. You can do this via aspnet identity( [How to add claims in ASP.NET Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383955/how-to-add-claims-in-asp-net-identity)) or you can write your own middleware.

Once you have claims, you need to create Policies. This is done via the `Startup.cs` class in the `ConfigureServices` method.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("HR", policy => policy.RequireClaim("HRTeam"));
            options.AddPolicy("Helpdesk", policy => policy.RequireClaim("HelpdeskTeam"));
        });
```

And then decorate your controllers/actions with the `Authorize` attribure

```
[Authorize(Policy="Helpdesk")]
public class HelpDeskController : Controller
```

Comment: I've added claims but its still not working as expected. Can you please see above for the edit?

Comment: I don't think you need to override the ClaimsPrincipal, you need to add Claims to it when you authenticate

Comment: Claims and Roles with and without Policies are all valid schemes for managing Authorization.

Comment: @ste-fu could you expand on this? I'm having the same problem and I'm not sure what you mean by "Adding claims when you authenticate"?

Currently I enable Windows Authentication using this line:

services.AddAuthentication(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

Comment: can we add multiple policy like this [Authorize(Policy="Helpdesk,Supervisor")] ?

Comment: Lots of good info here about multiple policies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609632/asp-net-5-authorize-against-two-or-more-policies-or-combined-policy

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem - the solutions given in the post weren't helpful but the comments pointed me in the right direction. You need to add claims to your ClaimsPrincipal.

Step 1: Create a ClaimsTransformer - Replace "Admin" and add a separate claim for each role you fetch from your database

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;

public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{ 
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var ci = (ClaimsIdentity) principal.Identity;
        var c = new Claim(ci.RoleClaimType, "Admin");
        ci.AddClaim(c);
        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    }
}
```

Step 2: Add your ClaimsTransformer to the ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
});

services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();
```

Step 3: You can now add Role based Authorization attributes within your Controllers

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[HttpGet("[action]/{id}")]        
public User GetUser([FromRoute] int id)
{
    UserLogic ul = new UserLogic();
    return ul.GetUser(id);
}
```

Comment: How did you get this to work? I did the same thing and I get "The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed"?

Comment: @CoderSteve did you ever figure this out? I'm getting the same problem.