# .NET Core 3.0 ClaimsTransformation

Tags: c#, .net-core, authorization, windows-authentication

Previously in .NET Framework I used a custom `RoleProvider` alongside Windows Authentication to deliver custom roles against the current principal as opposed to using Active Directory groups.

So, the goal is to be able to use the decorative `[Authorize(Roles="")]` attribute where the roles are coming from a database and not active directory (or a combination of both would be fine).

To achieve this in core I believe I need to use `IClaimsTransformation` to assign role claims as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51873269/asp-net-core-2-1-custom-roleprovider-with-windows-authentication#answer-53549574).

Here I'm just trying to add one role "Admin" however when I use `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` I get a 403 Unauthorised response.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddRazorPages();
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();
-------
app.UseAuthorization();
```

ClaimsTransformer.cs

```
    public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
            var c = new Claim(identity.RoleClaimType, "Admin");
            identity.AddClaim(c);
            return await Task.FromResult(principal);
        }
    }
```

Annoyingly this works when I call `User.IsInRole()` and I can see the group when I inspect the Claims so it is being added however it doesn't work with the Authorize attribute. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manged to solve this using `ClaimsTransformer` alongside a custom `TypeFilterAttribute`

ClaimsTransformer.cs

```
    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var identity = (WindowsIdentity)principal.Identity;

        Guid userGuid;

        SecurityIdentifier sid = identity.User;

        using (DirectoryEntry userDirectoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<SID=" + sid.Value + ">"))
        {
            userGuid = userDirectoryEntry.Guid;
        }

        UserAccount user = null;

        if (userGuid != Guid.Empty)
            user = await db.UserAccounts.Where(x => x.GUID == userGuid).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

        if (user == null)
            return principal;

        if (user.Historic)
            return principal;


        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        foreach (var role in user?.UserAccountGroups)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GroupSid, role.Group.Name));
        };

        identity.AddClaims(claims);

        return principal;
    }
```

GroupsAttribute.cs

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class GroupsAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public GroupsAttribute(string groups) : base(typeof(ClaimRequirementFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { groups };
    }
}

public class ClaimRequirementFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    readonly string _groups;

    public ClaimRequirementFilter(string groups)
    {
        _groups = groups;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {


        var groups = _groups.Split(',');
        bool hasClaim = false;
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.User.Claims.Any(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.GroupSid && c.Value.Equals(group.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                hasClaim = true;
        }

        if (!hasClaim)
        {
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I used something similar to give custom role-claims to the user depending on their Active Directory groups.

```
public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public ClaimsTransformer(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
       // AppRole has two string props, Displayname and AdGroup. Get Adgroup from appsettings.json.
        AppRole customRole = new AppRole() 
        {  
            DisplayName =_configuration.GetSection("Roles")
                    .GetSection("CustomRole")
                    .GetSection("DisplayName").Value,
            AdGroup = _configuration.GetSection("Roles")
                    .GetSection("CustomRole")
                    .GetSection("AdGroup").Value
        };
        if (principal.IsInRole(customRole.AdGroup))
        {
            Claim customRoleClaim = new Claim(claimsIdentity.RoleClaimType, "CustomRole");
            claimsIdentity.AddClaim(customRoleClaim);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    }
}
```

To get the Claimstransformer to work with the Authorize attribute, use this in Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   ...

   app.UseAuthorization();
   app.UseAuthentication();

   ...
}
```

I used it for Blazor, so it can be used like this in the Blazor Component.

To authorize the whole component:

```
    @attribute [Authorize(Roles = "CustomRole")]
```

or to authorize parts of the component:

```
    <AuthorizeView Roles="CustomRole">
        <Authorized>You are authorized</Authorized>
    </AuthorizeView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get authorization working via policy setup in the Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{               
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
    options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
});
```