# ASP.NET Authentication POST Policy

Tags: asp.net

I am currently working on a POST controller. In the past I've handled logic regarding authentication in the controller itself like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Foo foo)
    {
        if (foo.bar !== user.bar){
            return;
    }
```

I am not the best c# programmer, so have no clue how this should be handled. While researching I stumbled upon Policies. So I already use a [Authenticated] tag above the controller, but based on if the foo.bar in this example is the same as me.bar I am not allowed to make this post. (So the authenticated tag is for authentication but I want to change the Authorization)

Is it possible that I can make a [Policy=("fooPoster")] and can use the body of the post in there to determine whether I am authorized or not to access the post, or can I only access the global state to determine it?

Comment: Are you talking about something like this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @Jabberwocky This was what I ran into, yes. This seems to be for asp.net core, but I also saw it somewhat modified. Nevertheless I have less experience with this and couldn't conclude if I would be able to use the body of the post for the policy, other than that you can feed it a function (but it might be redundant to put the authorise logic somewhere else than in the controller)

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609632/asp-net-5-authorize-against-two-or-more-policies

Comment: Thank you! it seems to be a bit of overkill to try to fit it in there since its not just a field comparison!

Answer (score 0):

You can try custom authorization. Refer to the code below.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [CustomAuthorization(Foo.bar)]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Foo foo)
    {
        if (foo.bar !== user.bar)
        {
            return;
        }
    }



    public class CustomAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly string allowedroles;
    public CustomAuthorizationAttribute(string roles)
    {
        this.allowedroles = roles;
    }
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        bool authorize = false;
        if (Me.bar != allowedroles)
        {
            authorize = true;
        }
        return authorize;
    }
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```

For more details you can go through [here](https://medium.com/@piyalidas.gcetts/how-to-customized-theuser-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-86df06e142ca) :