# Authorize an action to Admin and only the user who created and event in dotnet core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, policy, authorize

I need to authorize the edit action method for **admin or only the users who created it**.

I am adding these policy

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("EditAnyEventPolicy", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.RequireRole("Admin");
    });
    options.AddPolicy("EditEventPolicy", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.RequireClaim("event_creator");
    });
});
```

```
[Authorize(Policy = "EditAnyEventPolicy")]
[Authorize(Policy = "EditEventPolicy")]
public IActionResult EditEvent()
{
    //code
}
```

The problem is that now users who have admin role and created the event can edit. I need an `OR` functionality.

How to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609632/asp-net-5-authorize-against-two-or-more-policies-or-combined-policy